# Samba's smbd no longer working with MIT Kerberos & OpenLDAP for authentication

Tags: samba, kerberos

I'm getting the following error when trying to browse a Samba share:

```
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_NO_IMPERSONATION_TOKEN
```

My Samba configuration for tying a standalone server's `smbd` to its MIT Kerberos and OpenLDAP setup used to work (definitely did with Ubuntu 20.04, can't recall if it ever did with Ubuntu 22.04):

```
<smb.conf>

[global]
# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = EXAMPLE

# The 'auto' setting here configures Samba based on the value of the
# 'security' setting.
   server role = auto

# Configure Samba to call out to Kerberos for all authentication. Because we're
# not also configuring a passdb, Samba will look to the system accounts for all
# authorization info (e.g. UIDs, groups, etc.). This setup was taken from
# https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-ldap.html.
   security = ads
   realm = EXAMPLE.COM
   kerberos method = dedicated keytab
   dedicated keytab file = /etc/samba/smbd.keytab

   idmap config * : backend = tdb
   idmap config * : range = 20001-30000
   idmap config {{ domain | upper }} : backend = rfc2307
   idmap config {{ domain | upper }} : range = 10000-20000
```

I could then grab a Kerberos ticket and browse and/or mount Samba shares, e.g.:

```
$ kinit
Password for coolcat@EXAMPLE.COM: 

$ /usr/bin/smbclient //neatbox.example.com/share --use-kerberos=required --no-pass --directory somepath --command ls
  .                                   D        0  Fri May  6 07:10:08 2022
  ..                                  D        0  Fri May  6 07:10:08 2022
  stuff                               D        0  Fri May  6 07:10:08 2022
  otherstuff                          D        0  Fri May  6 07:10:13 2022

        957134040 blocks of size 1024. 620537476 blocks available
```

A long while back, though, that stopped working (like a year or two ago; just haven't had time to sit down and fuss with it until now; parenting is, like, a lot, you know?). Now I get this:

```
$ /usr/bin/smbclient //neatbox.example.com/share --use-kerberos=required --no-pass --directory somepath --command ls
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_NO_IMPERSONATION_TOKEN
```

I've spent a couple nights researching now, and I think something broke or got removed around Samba 4.14? Something about PACs, which are apparently part of Kerberos tickets... somehow? [1, 2, 3] I don't know, I'm not a Kerberos expert; I just mash things on the keyboard until things work, like most folks.

So here's my main question: does Samba support authenticating via MIT Kerberos and OpenLDAP like it used to, or is that now deprecated/unsupported?

### Miscellany

The `smbd` log always has this in it, right after starting/restarting:

```
$ sudo systemctl status smbd
...
Dec 24 20:53:29 eddings systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
Dec 24 20:53:29 eddings smbd[782101]: [2023/12/24 20:53:29.593145,  0] ../../source3/smbd/server.c:1734(main)
Dec 24 20:53:29 eddings smbd[782101]:   smbd version 4.15.13-Ubuntu started.
Dec 24 20:53:29 eddings smbd[782101]:   Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2021
Dec 24 20:53:29 eddings systemd[1]: Started Samba SMB Daemon.
Dec 24 20:53:30 eddings smbd[782101]: [2023/12/24 20:53:30.244701,  0] ../../source3/printing/nt_printing.c:233(nt_printing_init)
Dec 24 20:53:30 eddings smbd[782101]:   nt_printing_init: error checking published printers: WERR_ACCESS_DENIED
```

Sometimes, not-reproducibly, it also ends up with a bunch of these errors:

```
Dec 24 11:06:27 eddings smbd[766136]: [2023/12/24 11:06:27.972690,  0] ../../source3/auth/auth_winbind.c:120(check_winbind_security)
Dec 24 11:06:27 eddings smbd[766136]:   check_winbind_security: winbindd not running - but required as domain member: NT_STATUS_NO_LOGON_SERVERS
```

Not sure if they're relevant, but the `smbclient` failures don't seem to trigger them, so... they're *likely* unrelated.

[1] https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14901 (I tried the `username map script` and `local nt token from` settings there and it didn't work)

[2] https://lists.fedorahosted.org/archives/list/freeipa-users@lists.fedorahosted.org/thread/6CTEYZ63WEPHR6GESDSUGNS57XGNTD2U/#6CTEYZ63WEPHR6GESDSUGNS57XGNTD2U

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PACs, "privilege attribute certificates," are a way for the KDC to attach extra information to Kerberos tickets. While normally a ticket only indicates the principal name and nothing else, the PAC can also provide the Windows SID, the group memberships, the home directory... avoiding the need for the server to fetch that from LDAP or somewhere. DCE and Active Directory use PACs everywhere; MIT/Heimdal Kerberos traditionally do not.

Samba, in recent versions, reworked its Kerberos support to close several major security holes. As part of the rework (perhaps an unnecessary part, but it did reduce code complexity), a Samba server that's part of an Active Directory domain requires PACs, while a Samba server that *isn't* an AD member does the opposite and completely rejects tickets that have PACs (as traditionally MIT Kerberos and Heimdal did not use them at all).

So the first problem is that you're using `security = ads` while not, in fact, having ADS at all. This option enables Samba's "Active Directory" mode and has it require PACs with AD-specific information in Kerberos tickets, which you cannot provide, which leads to the "NO_IMPERSONATION_TOKEN" error.

You don't need `security = ads` just to use Kerberos with Samba. Remove it and use the default security mode.

The second problem is that the above is slightly a lie and recently MIT Kerberos *did* start issuing tickets with PACs (to solve another security issue related to S4U)... although they're empty PACs that have none of the AD attributes that Samba in `ads` mode would require (no SID, no group memberships) – these PACs only exist for the sake of the digital signature they carry – so they will not satisfy Samba's ads-mode requirements.

However, those empty PACs are PACs nevertheless, and they will now be rejected by Samba when it's used as a standalone server, with a slightly different "BAD_TOKEN" error. To solve this, you'll need to mark the Samba `cifs/*` principals as not requiring a PAC:

```
# kadmin
kadmin:  modprinc +no_auth_data_required cifs/neatbox.example.com
```

...and throw away any cached tickets you may have for the service:

```
$ kinit -R
```

Comment: This is a very detailed and plausible sounding answer, so I’m marking it as accepted. Just a heads up for others, though, that I have not had a chance to go test this. For the time being, I’ve switched my Samba server entirely to user security/accounts, and that’s working well enough for me at the moment. I’ll try to get Kerberos working again sometime in the future, when I need it.

Answer (score 1):

Samba is a suite of daemons working together. For quite few years if you are running a domain member configuration, winbindd must be running as well. Make sure both smbd and winbindd are running. smbd used to have a fallback code to handle tasks that are now fully handled by the winbindd.